# Rails 3 - model issue, foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two models, Like and Photo.

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photo, :class_name => "DataLike", :foreign_key => "photo_id"
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :likes
end
```

And now I try to execute this query:

```
query = Like.select(:photo_id).joins(:photo).count
```

But I am still getting this error:

> uninitialized constant Like::DataLike

Could anyone help me, please, what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to have a `DataLike` model, my best guess is that you want to link to the `Photo` model:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photo, :foreign_key => "photo_id"
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :likes
end
```

If you leave out the `:class_name` option, the `Photo` model is inferred. It's used to specify the class of the linked model, in case it is different from the association name.